# orthogonal projection of a vector onto a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

I am trying to find the orthogonal projection of a vector $\vec u= (1,-1,2)$ onto a plane which has three points $\vec a=(1,0,0)$ ,$\vec b=(1,1,1)$, and $\vec c=(0,0,1)$. I started by projecting $\vec u$ onto $\vec a$ and projecting the same vector onto $\vec c$ and finally adding both projections ,but I am not getting what I am expecting. Can someone please help?

Comment: This plane does not pass through the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to guess the equation of the plane as $x-y+z=1$ from which you see that the normal is $(1,-1,1)$. To find the projection choose $\alpha$ such that $(1,-1,2)+\alpha (1,-1,1)$ lies in the plane $x-y+z=1$. This gives $\alpha =-1$ and the projection is nothing but $\vec c=(0,0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can work out the normal to the plane by computing $$\vec n=(\vec a-\vec b)\times (\vec b- \vec c)$$where $\times$ is the vector cross product. Then project your vector $\vec u$ onto this normal to get $\vec u_\parallel$. Then the required projection onto the plane is $$\vec u_\perp=\vec u-\vec u_\parallel+\vec a$$ where the $\vec a$ is added on to ensure the vector lies on the plane, rather than lying parallel to the plane, but starting at the origin.

Comment: ,Thank you for your answer it was very helpfull  .

Comment: The formula for the normal is wrong. For example try to find the normal to the plane defined by $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$. The normal should be along $(1,1,1)$. The correct way is $\vec n=(\vec a-\vec b)\times(\vec a-\vec c)$

Comment: @Andrei yes, you're right, you need to pick two coplanar vectors.

Comment: Better, but still wrong. The $\vec u_\perp$ obtained per your answer doesn’t lie on the plane. You appear to be making the same fundamental error as the OP in neglecting the fact that this plane doesn’t pass through the origin.

Comment: @amd yep, thats right, thanks

Comment: @JohnDoe: Thanks for showing how to calculate the plane normal given three points! Could you do (n x u) x n to get the vector u projection on that plane (maybe (n x u) x n + a to ensure the projection lies on the plane if needed)?