# What happens to the $d$ part of the plane equation $x+y+z=d$ when preforming a vector projection onto the plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

So i am working with vector projection and given a vector $v=(3,4,0)$ and a plane $x+y+z=1$ i am supposed to find the projection of $v$ onto the plane. The logical step is to just use the normal vector of the plane $n$ and do a projection $proj_n v=(v*n)/(n*n)*n$. But when i draw up the vectors and the plane, the projection is not onto the plane because of the $D$ part of the plane equation where $D=1$.

Is this the right way to solve these kinds of problems or if not what do i need to do solve it?

Comment: This seems like it’s basically a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3054495/265466. However, usage varies: you should compare this problem that you’ve been given to other examples in the same course to tell if the answer really be a point on the plane or a vector parallel to it. In the latter case, you simply ignore $d$.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find the projection of a vector $v$ to a plane with normal $n$ is to think of  the line $g(t)=v+t\cdot n$ and compute the intersection with your given plane.

As you are given the plane in coordinate form, we can directly see the normal vector to be $n=(1,1,1)$ and we know $v=(3,4,0)$.

Putting it all in the coordinate form equation, we get
$$ 
3+t+4+t+0+t=1\\
\Leftrightarrow 7+3t =1\\
\Leftrightarrow t = -2
$$

Thus, the projection onto the plane is
$$
g(-2)=(3,4,0)-2\cdot(1,1,1)=(1,2,-1)
$$

A short check shows that the coordinate form fulfills 
$$ 1+2-1=1,$$ so this is really inside the plane :)

Answer (score -1):

$\textrm{proj}_n v = \frac{v\cdot n}{n \cdot n} n$ is the component of the vector normal to the plane. So the component of the vector parallel to the plane is $v - \textrm{proj}_n v$, or, in this case, $w=\left( \frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{3},-\frac{7}{3}\right)$.

The value of $d$ doesn't come into it regardless, because we only care about the direction of the vector and the plane. But you can check your work by taking a random point $P$ in the plane, e.g., $(1,1,-1)$, and verifying that $P + w$ is also in the plane.

You can also verify that $w \cdot \textrm{proj}_n v = 0$ and that $w + \textrm{proj}_n v = v$.

Comment: When one is asked to project _onto_ a plane, the solution must be a point on the plane, not a vector parallel to it. You’ve done precisely the same incorrect thing that the OP described in the question.

Comment: That's not how projection onto a plane is defined, @amd. Projection of a vector onto a plane is the component of the vector in the plane. OP found the component _orthogonal_ to the plane. The projection of a vector is a _vector_, not a point. The relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) gives the standard definition.

Comment: It most certainly is. That article only discusses projection onto vector subspaces of a vector space, e.g., planes through the origin In $\mathbb R^3$, so isn’t apropos here since $x+y+z=1$ doesn’t include the origin. See the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3054495/265466), which is effectively a duplicate of this one, for the correct approach.

Comment: The vector $w$ lies in the plane $x+y+z=1$. Or, to be more precise, the vector $w$ is tangent to the plane in the three-dimensional vector space at each point on the plane. If one were to regard $(3,4,0)$ as a _point_, then its orthogonal projection to the plane would be Nurator's point $(1,2,-2)$. But that wasn't the problem. The vector $(1,2,-2)$ does not lie in the plane. It "points at it" from the origin, if we regard it as an element of the vector space at the origin. Of course it depends on usage, but what I'm describing is pretty common usage in undergrad linear algebra courses.

Comment: You can see [here](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408m/Display12-5-4.shtml), for example, to see how vectors are typically spoken of as being "in" a plane not passing through the origin. The kind of projection I'm talking about is used to find the component of force directed along a surface in space.

Comment: I agree that the wording is pretty bad. I really disliked the usage as vector for the point as well. But I still think that my solution is the one the question was supposed to ask.

Comment: You may be right. But I teach linear algebra, and my solution is the one I would expect a student to give if I asked a question worded in that way. It's hard to say more without knowing the context, but my solution answers the question that was literally asked. There is a geometrical significance to projecting a point to a plane (which is what you do) and to projecting a vector to a plane (which is what I do). But, regarding $(1,2,-2)$ as a _vector_, it goes against any usage I've seen to refer to it as lying in the given plane. And it's not obvious to me what use such a vector would have.

Comment: Those same undergraduate courses you cite don’t make the fine distinction between points and vectors that you’re making. If that’s the level of rigor in your teaching, then kudos! The only way to know for sure what the usage is in this case is for the OP to compare this problem to other examples in the same course.

Comment: The distinction between vectors and points is elementary. It's made in the course modules I linked, which are typical. Many courses use different notation for that reason. Anyone using vectors for physical applications would want to distinguish between geometrical objects and vector quantities. It may be that OP or their instructor used imprecise language. But my solution solves the question that was asked. Further, the projection of a vector to a plane is likelier to be of interest than the vector that happens to point at a plane from some arbitrary origin.